# Colour formatting according the type of the item in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, formatting

I started building an excel spreadsheet with a database of items in Microsoft Excel 2010. Those items have some fixed max values on its properties according the type of them. Those values are stored in another hidden table according the type of the item and of course are different in each of them. For example the hidden table its something like this:

### Type  | Price | Warranty

TV    | 1683  | 4

PC    | 1210  | 1

A/C   | 1234  | 2

So now whenever i create a new item in my main table those properties will get a data bar color formatting compared to the other hidden table! Like:

TV | Sony Bravia RT219  | 1293 | 2

...and those "1293" and "2" values needs to get a data bar "comparing" the "1293" value with the max "1683" and so on...

I wish that you can understand me. Which formula i have to use so i can make this possible in ms excel 2010?

Comment: Have you tried to create any VBA yet? You should paste it in or at least allude to it, to give a clearer idea of exactly what you need. People are more willing to take time to help if you've already put in your own effort.

Comment: No i dont know how i can create a vba. I thought that it just needs a conditional formating formula like this `=MAX(IF(Database!$A$2:$A$100000=Max!$A$2:$A$15))` but i can get it done :/

Comment: Conditional formatting can't handle that, a VBA OnUpdate trigger is probably the best bet. That's so much more complex, though; are you sure you don't want to use Access instead? Relatively simple queries from an Access database to Excel can return numbers that you can use to format with.

Comment: Hmm i think that i can handle excel better so i ll wait if someone can help me do this in excel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do what you want using worksheet functions (no vba) and conditional formatting

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A1:A3,0),2,1,1,"Sheet2"))
```

Sheet2!A1:A3 is a reference to your hidden list, mine only has 3

It looks at the value of A1 on the first sheet, tries to find it in the hidden sheet.
If it finds a result, MATCH() returns its row number.
ADDRESS() then returns the address of the 2nd column on the MATCH() row in sheet2
INDIRECT() then gets the value of it.

MATCH(LOOKUPVALUE,LOOKUPLIST,MATCHTYPE)
ADDRESS(ROW, COLUMN, ABSOLUTE, A1/R1C1, SHEET)
INDIRECT(ADDRESS)

you should be able to have it pull all the information from the 2nd sheet using that.

dont have time to explain anymore, but the functions aren't that hard to figure out

**update**

made a simple example https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10316127/example.xlsx

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH([SEARCH_VALUE],Sheet2!$A:$A,0),[COLUMN],1,1,"Sheet2"))
```

[SEARCH_VALUE] is a Cell in your visible sheet containing the "Type" you want to lookup.

[COLUMN] is the column number that corresponds to the column you want to read from. (2 for Max Price and 3 for Warranty)

I didn't really understand your last comment, so without an example or a slightly more detailed explanation of what you need I cant help much more.

Comment: Hmm i tried this: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(E5,Hidden!A2:A15,0),2,1,1,"Hidden"))` and i get that the formula contains and error

Comment: The 2nd Argument in MATCH() should be a single column, the one with TV, A/C whatever

Comment: You can probably replace the "Hidden!$A$2:$A$50" in the match with "Hidden!$A:$A" so you dont have to keep modifying the equation if you add more items to the hidden sheet.

Comment: Hmm i think that this formula only checks for equal row values and not columns. I tried to implement a match on columns also but cant get it done. I want to be able to check max values in both row and column equal values so i can add more easily

Comment: Both Row and Column? Surely your hidden sheet only has 3 Columns "Type", "Max Price" and "Warranty". The formula (with the correct column number in) will return either "Max Price" or "Warranty" for any given "Type".

Comment: nick at nickslash dot co dot uk